# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed context instance. ApplicationDbContext _db variable is disposed

Tags: c#, .net, rest, entity-framework, objectdisposedexception

I catch exception in my API. This is code of service, when I am calling any methods of any repositories apart from selectAll() method I catch such mistake. Also, I catch this exception when I use LINQ with SelectAll() object.

```
using Journal.DAL.Interfaces;
using Journal.Domain.Models;
using Journal.Domain.Responses;
using Journal.Domain.JsonModels;
using Journal.Service.Interfaces;
using Journal.Domain.ResponseModels;

namespace Journal.Service.Implementations
{
    public class MTAccountService : IMTAccountService
    {
        private readonly IMTAccountRepository _mtAccountRepository;
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
        private readonly IMTDataRepository _mtDataRepository;

        public MTAccountService(IMTAccountRepository mtAccountRepository, IUserRepository userRepository, IMTDataRepository mtDataRepository)
        {
            _mtAccountRepository = mtAccountRepository;
            _userRepository = userRepository;
            _mtDataRepository = mtDataRepository;
        }

        public async Task<BaseResponse<MTAccountResponseModel>> AddAccount(MTAccountJsonModel accountModel)
        {
            var response = new BaseResponse<MTAccountResponseModel>();
            try
            {
                var accounts = await _mtAccountRepository.SelectAll();
                if (accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Login == accountModel.Login) != null)
                {
                    response.StatusCode = Domain.Enums.StatusCode.ERROR;
                    response.Message = "Account exists";
                    return response;
                }
                if (!await _mtDataRepository.Initialize(accountModel))
                {
                    response.StatusCode = Domain.Enums.StatusCode.ERROR;
                    response.Message = "Account initializing error";
                    return response;
                }
                    var account = new MTAccount();

                account.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                account.Login = accountModel.Login;
                account.Password = accountModel.Password;
                account.Server = accountModel.Server;
                account.UserId = accountModel.UserId;
                var users = await _userRepository.SelectAll();
                account.User = users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == accountModel.UserId);

                if (await _mtAccountRepository.Create(account))
                    {
                        response.StatusCode = Domain.Enums.StatusCode.OK;
                        response.Data = new MTAccountResponseModel(account);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response.StatusCode = Domain.Enums.StatusCode.ERROR;
                        response.Message = "DB Error";
                    }

            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            { 
                response.StatusCode=Domain.Enums.StatusCode.ERROR;
                response.Message=ex.Message;
            }
            return response;
        }

        public async Task<BaseResponse<bool>> DeleteMTAccount(Guid accountId)
        {
            var response = new BaseResponse<bool>();
            try
            {
                var accounts = await _mtAccountRepository.SelectAll();
                var account = accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == accountId);
                if(account == null)
                {
                    response.Data = false;
                    response.StatusCode = Domain.Enums.StatusCode.ERROR;
                    response.Message = "Account with such Id does not exists";
                }
                else
                {
                    if(await _mtAccountRepository.Delete(account))
                    {
                        response.Data = true;
                        response.StatusCode = Domain.Enums.StatusCode.OK;
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response.Data = false;
                        response.StatusCode = Domain.Enums.StatusCode.ERROR;
                        response.Message = "DB error";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.Data = false;
                response.StatusCode = Domain.Enums.StatusCode.ERROR;
                response.Message = ex.Message;
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

This is repository, that place when exception occures. It says that ApplicationDbContext variable was disposed

```
using Journal.DAL;
using Journal.DAL.Interfaces;
using Journal.Domain.Models;

namespace Journal.DAL.Repositories
{
    public class MTAccountRepository : IMTAccountRepository
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public MTAccountRepository(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public async Task<bool> Create(MTAccount entity)
        {
            await _db.MTAccounts.AddAsync(entity);
            await  _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }

        public async Task<bool> Delete(MTAccount entity)
        {
            _db.MTAccounts.Remove(entity);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }

        public async Task<bool> Edit(MTAccount entity)
        {
            _db.MTAccounts.Update(entity);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }

        public async Task<IQueryable<MTAccount>> SelectAll()
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(_db.MTAccounts);
        }
    }
}
```

This is builder

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var connection = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection), optionsLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Singleton);

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMTAccountRepository, MTAccountRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISubscriptionRepository, SubscriptionRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMTDataRepository, MTDataRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMTAccountService, MTAccountService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMTDataService, MTDataService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISubscriptionService, SubscriptionService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMTDealRepository, MTDealRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I tried all possible solutions from Internet. Using different lifetime options and using sync instead of async methods.

Comment: On which line exactly do you have the exception ?

Comment: There's no reason to make SelectAll async.  It returns a query, not data.  It's the subsequent FirstOrDefault, ToList, etc that actually run the query and should be async. 

Anyway that's not causing your error.  Somewhere you're using the DbContext outside of the some of a single HTTP request.

Comment: I suspect some other type (which is not including in your code in the Q) takes a reference to the `ApplicationDbContext` instance from DB, and disposes it. (Normally when the DI scope is torn down, as part of the request completing) will dispose of all objects created in that scope that are disposable. OR some async task is not awaited (so lives on beyond the request's scope's cleanup).

Comment: Check if you use using anywhere in your application the db disposes after using block
check if you are using Dispose anywhere in the project
Check if any Dependency injection is not doing what is expected
Check if in any async you dont dispose before every action is awaited

Answer (score 1):

Returning `IQueryable` from async method has no sense. There is no database request. It is query ready for execution.

Make this method synchronous:

```cs
public IQueryable<MTAccount> SelectAll()
{
    return _db.MTAccounts;
}
```

Also use `await FirstOrDefaultAsync` - it is real database call.

Make this change and analyse where you store `IQueryable`. Enumerating `IQueryable` returned by context, which disposed before enumeration, throws this exception.

Comment: All these notes make sense, I agree. But It did not solve the problem. Anyway, after DB call I catch an exception System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed context instance. ApplicationDbContext _db variable is disposed

Comment: I cannot debug your code. And no one can do that. You have used `IQueryable` from disposed context. Find and fix that.

Comment: Thanks, I will see. But how can I find where have dispose been called if I do not call it manually and I did not find any info about its call in callstack